# Remove some default created fallback routes

Tags: routes, cakephp-3.x

In CakePHP 3 the default behavour is DashedRoutes, which I am happy with. However, in some instances, I want to replace the routes with my own custom routes and remove the default created routes. My routes file looks like this:

```
<?php
use Cake\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware;
use Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder;
use Cake\Routing\Router;
use Cake\Routing\Route\DashedRoute;

Router::defaultRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);

Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->registerMiddleware('csrf', new CsrfProtectionMiddleware([
        'httpOnly' => true
    ]));

    $routes->applyMiddleware('csrf');

    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);

    $routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);

    $routes->connect('/register', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'register']);
    $routes->connect('/login', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
    $routes->connect('/logout', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'logout']);

    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

In this case, I want the following routes to not work and basically return a 404 error:

```
/users/login
/users/logout
/users/register
```

How would I 'disconnect' these routes?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can just set another route for `/users/*` that goes to a 404-redirect function, basically adding this to the route:

```php
$routes->connect(
    '/users/*',
    ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'serve404']
);
```

And then this to the UsersController (or if you want AppController for later reuse):

```php
public function serve404(){
    throw NotFoundException();
}
```

Comment: There is various workarounds, but was hoping for a built in solution to deleting a route. I'll keep this in mind. Thanks.